# getting a django textfeild to run as code

Tags: python, django, django-views, exec

I'm trying to get a project going and I'm using Django to do it. I have as one of my attributes in models `start_lines = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)`. These lines are to get code started with the `exec()` function. As one of them, I have

```
from .code.Lot_sizing_codes import lot_size
ls = lot_size(K, h, r, True)
output, extra_output = (ls.{str(Functions.objects.get(id=request.POST["function_to_call"]))}({request.POST["inputExtras"]}))
```

I have to run this through function to render what i want:

```
def showProgramX(request, pk):
    program = Program.objects.get(id=pk)
    form = ProgramInputForm()
    keys = ""
    vars = []
    for var in program.inputvariables.split(","):
        var_name, var_type = var.split("=")
        keys += f"""
            <tr>
            <th><label for="{var_name}">{var_name}:</label></th>
            <td><input type="text" name="{var_name}" maxlength="1000" class="input" id="id_inputvariables"></td>
            </tr>"""
        vars.append(var_name)
    content = {"program": program, "form": form, "keys": keys}
    if request.method == "POST":
        form1 = ProgramInputForm(request.POST)
        import json

        req = request.POST
        for var in vars:
            line = f"""{var} = {req[f'{var}']}"""
            exec(line, globals())
       
        exec(program.start_lines, globals())
        content["output"] = output
        content["extra_output"] = extra_output
        content['form'] = form1
    return render(request, "programs/program.html", content)
```

the output if i print `program.start_lines` should be
in this case {str(Functions.objects.get(id=request.POST["function_to_call"]))} = all
and {request.POST["inputExtras"]} is nothing/empty

```
from .code.Lot_sizing_codes import lot_size
ls = lot_size(K, h, r, True)
output, extra_output = (ls.all())
```

where as I actually get

```
from .code.Lot_sizing_codes import lot_size
ls = lot_size(K, h, r, True)
output, extra_output = (ls.{str(Functions.objects.get(id=request.POST["function_to_call"]))}({request.POST["inputExtras"]}))
```

Does anyone know what I can do to get around this, I've tried everything I can.

Answer (score 0):

I got it. So now just sharing the knowledge.

I used  templates got inspired by https://realpython.com/python-string-formatting/

```
from string import Template 
t = Template(program.start_lines)
print(t.substitute(function =str(Functions.objects.get(id=request.POST["function_to_call"])), argskwargs=request.POST["inputExtras"] ))
```

and put the following in the text field

```
from .code.Lot_sizing_codes import lot_size
ls = lot_size(K, h, r, True)
output, extra_output = (ls.$function($argskwargs))
```